# How to make a refresh in browser with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have an app is in iis, it is an app made in angularjs and webapi C # 2.0, I would like to create a task that updates the browser as soon as I save any js file.

Version of gulp: 3.9.1

```
gulp.task('livereload', function () {
    gulp.watch(config.files.js);
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## [gulp-livereload](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload)

> A lightweight gulp plugin for livereload to be used with the
>   [livereload chrome extension](http://livereload.com/extensions/) or a [livereload middleware](https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload).

Simple to setup:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('less', function() {
  gulp.src('less/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('less/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

## [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp)

> There's no official Browsersync plugin for Gulp, because it's not
>   needed! You simply `require` the module, utilise the [API](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/api) and configure
>   it with [options](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options).

The new cool kid, most have already moved to it.

> Streams are supported in Browsersync, so you can call reload at
>   specific points during your tasks and all browsers will be informed of
>   the changes. Because Browsersync only cares about your CSS when it's
>   finished compiling - make sure you call `.stream()` after `gulp.dest`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
        // or
        // proxy: 'yourserver.dev'
    });

    gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

For a manual reload:

```
// ...
var reload = browserSync.reload;

// Save a reference to the `reload` method

// Watch scss AND html files, doing different things with each.
gulp.task('serve', function () {

    // Serve files from the root of this project
    browserSync.init({/* ... */});

    gulp.watch("*.html").on("change", reload);
});
```

[Why Browsersync is better?](https://www.slant.co/versus/5065/5066/~livereload_vs_browsersync)

> It is not constrained to a single device, it works across desktop and
>   mobile devices at the same time. It will update code changes,
>   synchronize scroll positions and form inputs automatically across all
>   browsers and devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck with browsersync not listening to changes made in .css after being compiled (using less here), but then you showed me I was missing `.pipe(browserSync.stream())`. I will remember this one whenever I need to create a listening method!

Comment: @Emile Bergson I wanted to try livereload because I'd had trouble getting browsersync set up in the past and it was kind of overkill for what I needed but it does not seem to be working. Do you know if livereload has changed in the last couple of years?

Comment: @DavidA.French Never used these libraries. I just know they exist. Now, the thing most people are using is Webpack with the dev server and hot module reload.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yeah I've used webpack before. It's kind of a pain for static html stuff or simple wp themes so I've been also learning gulp because I find it a lot more lightweight. 

Anyway, thanks!