# browsersync does not reload when there are changes in .css

Tags: css, gulp

browsersync does not inject the css correctly, what could be happening ?, This is my code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', () =>
gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        sourceComments:true
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
);

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(["*.*"], {
        proxy: "http://localhost/wordpress_25denoviembre"
    });
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['sass']);

});
```

So far, it detects all types of .html .php .js file, but when compiling from .scss to .css it does not do anything. As you can see I have 2 consoles, 1 executes gulp (to compile sass) and the other (browser-sync).

I appreciate your help in advance.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hope that these links will help you:

[https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415506/how-to-make-a-refresh-in-browser-with-gulp)

[How to make a refresh in browser with gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415506/how-to-make-a-refresh-in-browser-with-gulp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the truth is that I'm a rookie with js, I tried to find the error, testing here and there, the updated my publication by placing my gulp code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

```
gulp.task('sass', () =>

  // added return below
  return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        sourceComments:true
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))

    // remove below
    //  .pipe(sass())

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))

    // added below
   .pipe(browserSync.stream());
);

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(["*.*"], {
        proxy: "http://localhost/wordpress_25denoviembre"
    });

    // remove below
    // .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```